# Prons and Cons of using relational Databases (like SQL) for real-time time series analysis?

Tags: sql, time-series, bigdata, relational-database

I know that the relational databases are not scalable to Big-Data. I also know that memcaching is a bit complicated in them. I also know that you may need to unnest and flatten data to prepare it for analysis.

However, I still think that for structured data, for some scenarios, it is better to apply them rather than time series databases like InfluxDB.

I do not think that sending queries causes latency and make relational databases inappropriate for time-series analysis. I could not find my answer [here]. So, my question is when we can use Relational databases for Time-Series analysis?